# How to handle multiple popup alerts with Serenity's PageObject

Tags: java, junit, alert, pageobjects, serenity-bdd

Here's the issue. I am using **Serenity** to run tests in **Internet Explorer** and `PageObject` is handling all my actions, either through Serenity's steps or by direct reference in **Junit's** tests.

The scenario I am currently working on is simple:

1. Enter date into a field (input "99999999").
2. Click Submit button.
3. Get popup alert messages.

   - Get "The year is invalid." msg first.
   - Get "Invalid Receipt Date format." msg second.

However, `PageObject` seems to immediately jump to the second message and completely ignores the first one. My implementation is somewhere along these lines:

```
@Test
public void receiptDateFieldIncorrectDateFormat() {
    page.open();
    steps.inputIntoReceiptDateField("99999999");
    steps.clickSubmitButton();
    String firstMsg = page.getAlert().getText();
    page.getAlert().accept();
    String secondMsg = page.getAlert().getText();
    page.getAlert().accept();
    Assert.assertEquals("The year is invalid.", firstMsg);
    Assert.assertEquals("Invalid Receipt Date format.", secondMsg);
}
```

Can someone explain to me how this works and why is the first alert omitted? `PageObject` does not seem to have functionality to cycle through multiple alerts.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Below is what the **JavaScript** looks like. Similar `if` statement is executed for the second `Alert`.

```
temp = inputDate.substring(0, 4);
//alert("year " + temp);
if (temp > 2500 || temp < 1940) {
    alert ("The year is invalid");
    return false;
}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JDelorean the reason as far as i know is that alert has been popped up before selenium code reacted to the alert code. Hence its wise to add some delay in between the alert code. Something like i did as follows

```
@Test public void receiptDateFieldIncorrectDateFormat() {

    page.open();

    steps.inputIntoReceiptDateField("99999999");

    steps.clickSubmitButton();

Thread.sleep(3000);

    String firstMsg = page.getAlert().getText();

    page.getAlert().accept();

Thread.sleep(3000);
    String secondMsg = page.getAlert().getText();

    page.getAlert().accept();

    Assert.assertEquals("The year is invalid.", firstMsg);

    Assert.assertEquals("Invalid Receipt Date format.", secondMsg);

}
```

or you can use something like

```
> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);  
> wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response selva. I tried `wait.until()` approach already - no result. I'll try `Thread.sleep()` and let you know what the outcome is.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those solutions works. Also, `Thread.sleep()` does not seem to be the right way to go regardless of it working or not.

Comment: can you share me your java code and also if possible the HTML for that alert ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is an internal business system. My code is pretty much the same as above. The Submit btn executes a javascript method call once pressed. The field format checks, I assume, are done by javascript also and that's where the alerts originate from.

Comment: Ok, allow me to be more specific here, there's a HTML call to JavaScript method. JavaScript then processes the input from the field: 1) verifies the year format, 2) prompts first alert, 3) prompts second alert.

Comment: without using the page object try using
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
  System.out.println(alert.getText());
  alert.dismiss() or accept();

Comment: Thanks selva, but this does not solve the problem. I have been trying to look up this issue on the web and it looks like JavaScript will execute its code (throw both Alerts) regardless of Webdriver's `wait()` or `switch()` methods. `wait()`, after all, does not pause the execution of webpage script but only the Java test one. This means I need to: pause the browser after it displays first alert >> handle it with WebDriver >> unpause browser and display second alert >> again handle it with WebDriver.

Comment: JDelorena can you confirm.. Was that an alert or some popup windows ?

Comment: I just edited my question, hope it provides more clarity now. The alert window looks like anything Windows/Internet Explorer would display.